# Designing a galvanically isolated analog transmission circuit with IL300 and different power supplies on both sides

Tags: analog, opto-isolator

I'm having trouble understanding how this circuit (suggested in the datasheet of the [IL300](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf)) would behave with a different power supply on both sides of the opto-coupling.

The datasheet assumes that both sides get the same supply voltage, but would it even work (or at least reliably so) if they didn't have the same voltage? It's shown in the image which supply voltages would be changed (Vcc to Vdd), just for clarity.

[image]

Comment: It will work fine provided the supply voltages are in the proper range on each side. The grounds also should not be the same (or there's no reason for the isolator).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the circuit will work nicely. The supply voltages do not have to be the same value. They should be completely isolated supplies (example: Two different batteries of different voltages.)

The voltage \$V_{a}-V_{b}\$ is amplified to the output causing \$I_{F}\$ to flow through the resistor and LED.

The light emitted from the LED, is linear with the driving current, is received by the photodiode between pins 3 and 4. The feedback current \$I_{p1}=K_{1}I_{F}\$.

The photodiode is a **current source** that is linearly dependent on the light intensity independent of \$V_{CC}\$ by Einstein's photo-electric effect.

\$I_{F}\$ keeps increasing until \$V_{b}=I_{p1}R_{1}=V_{a}\$

So now that the light from the LED represents the input voltage \$V_{in}\$ the current \$I_{p2}\$ sourced by the other photodiode also represents the \$V_{in}\$. Because the photodiode is also a current source the current is independent of \$V_{DD}\$.

\$I_{p2}\$ flows through \$R_{2}\$ which is calibrated so that \$V_{c}=V_{in}\$. \$U_{2}\$ is a voltage follower to buffer \$V_{c}\$ so that \$V_{out}=V_{in}\$.

Current sources have a limiting voltage called the compliance voltage. The voltage supply (\$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{CC}\$ set that compliance voltage as shown in Spehro Pefhany's answer. It limits the maximum current available from the diode.

Very nice circuit. Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I belive my misconception came from the idea that both photodiodes should be polarized by the same voltage so the current-light curve was the same for both, but I understand that it's not needed, because even with different currents through each photodiode, they'll still be proportional to the light emitted by the LED, even if the proportionality constant is different.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's missing here is that the [IL300](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf) datasheet does not (that I can see anyway) tell you how the photocurrent behaves with different reverse biases.

From this [Hamamatsu](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/si_pd_kspd9001e.pdf) app note we have a PD characteristic curve. As you can see, if you keep the photocurrent in the right range, and the reverse bias **high enough**, the photocurrent is virtually independent of the reverse bias:

[image]

There *will* be an error in the transfer gain of as much as ~+/-50% (the exact limits are given in the datasheet) however that's primarily a matter of the matching of the two photodiodes and other factors, not because of the bias voltage differences in a well designed system.